# Android studio 1.2.2 fails to import library

Tags: android

I have the following bulid.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.onlinecomments.android"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    //The below is the one that is failing
    compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.3.2'

    }
```

I did the "Sync Now" that shows on the page and I did "Tools -> Android -> Sync Project With Gradle Files" and both failed to import the library, so when I do "Alt + Enter" on the below I don't get the "Import class"

```
CircularProgressView cpb;
```

So what I did next is that I created a test android project and the import was successful, anyone had this issue and made it work?

Please note that the program compiles just fine without the last library I noted above.

Comment: Situation like this I make the following, then look for an answer :-) : 1. Make sure gradle is not set to work offline. 2. Clean & Build. 3. Remove then re-add the dependency. Also if it's like you said that it works in another project, your last resort is to make a new project and re-add the sources.

Comment: you should answer it because it worked :)

Comment: What exactly worked? Or you applied all of them?

Comment: I cleaned & rebuild it.

Comment: Thanks man for you quick response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Situations like this I make the following, then look for an answer :-) :

1. Make sure gradle is not set to work offline.
2. Clean & Build.
3. Remove then re-add the dependency.

Also if it's like you said that it works in another project, your last resort is to make a new project and re-add the sources.